# Regex - Ignore variable with no parameters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to implement JavaScript regular expression on the following string:

```
{{global_now_date}}-{{report date, [[YYYY]]}}-{{report date, [[MM]]}}-{{job_id}}_test_1_{{bca clause}}-Rev-{{report revision no.}}
```

I want to find the following:

```
{{report date, [[YYYY]]}}

{{report date, [[MM]]}}
```

And not find:

```
{{global_now_date}}
```

I can get the back part of the regular expression, but not the front part.

eg. date, `\[{2}.*?\]{2}}{2}` but I can't get the front part right.

Comment: will you plz add some code .

Comment: can you give an example and code as well.

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your regex `[{2}.*?]{2}` you specify a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which could match the characters `{` `2` `}` `.` `*` `?` 2 times `{2}`.
That is followed by matching a curly brace 2 times `}{2}`.

That would match for example `??}}`

Maybe this matches what you are looking for:

[`{{2}report date.*?}{2}`](https://regex101.com/r/WQV8mk/1)

This matches:

- Match 2 times a curly brace `{{2}`
- Match `report date`
- Match any character zero or more times non greedy `.*?`
- Match 2 times a closing curly brace `}{2}`